# Particles or Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, particles

thank you so much for all the fast responses I truly appreciate it. I have another question I've been wondering about, so I am working mobile game and I want to keep the size as small as possible. So I wanted to know does using Unity particle effects, impact performance and game size? I was wondering, if i wanted to make a visual effect of breaking apart a GameObject when destroyed, should I use unity particle system to do so? or should I make an animation of that game object breaking and use that instead?

to summeize should I be making animation for things such as rain effects and confetti and fire effect instead of making them with the particle system? is there any drawback to using one over the other?

Comment: You can use the particle system as long as you don’t overdo the particle numbers

Comment: Making a particle system vs an animation allows for much faster iteration and modification to existing vfx. An animation is much more fixed and takes longer to edit. If you want more modularity and customization go with particle system. Performance is fine as long as the system is not overdone.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I appreciate your help and fast respond.

Answer (score 0):

As TEEBQNE said it is your choice between animations and the particle system depending on what you need. If your team is small or you are a single developer it is best to opt for the particle system for the flexibility of changes and quick execution.

Optimising the particle system is not hard, just make sure you don't overdo the numbers and avoid some common mistakes. There is a list of the best practices for optimization on mobile games found [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/optimizing-particle-effects-for-mobile-applications#60385fb9edbc2a001e43bd62)

You can also find some pretty good looking particles premade in the unity asset store, which are already optimized well.